# TextBox : Wrapping text to multiple lines

Tags: c#, .net

I have a TextBox in my form and I am trying to wrap the content into multiple lines so that it doesn't get chopped off.

So far I did this,

```
TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();
myTextBox.Multiline = true;
myTextBox.WordWrap = true;
```

I tried various combinations of above, by setting `Multiline` to false and then `WordWrap` to false.

But nothing seems to work.

I found that there's a TextWrapping property too, but for some reason that's not available for my TextBox, probably because of a different .Net version.

Is there a way to wrap the content of a TextBox into multiple lines?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Text never get's wrapped into multiple lines. It always get's shown in one line.

Comment: Do you have a designer or no?

Comment: make sure your textbox is allowed to occupy enough height for more than one line of text. if your textbox has Height=24 (or whatever that number is) then the text will be forced to not wrap

Comment: No information about what GUI framework is being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your content? Is it a "human readable" string (e.g. 'normal' words and sentences), or is it a hexadecimal string etc.?

Depending on your content, you have multiple options:

1. Insert a `\n` after a certain amount of characters
2. Depending on your framework (WPF, WinForms etc.) use different properties / implementations.....

   If you are using WPF, try `AcceptReturn="true" TextWrapping="Wrap"`

   If you are using WinForms, try inserting some `\n`-characters , when `.Multiline := true` and `.WordWrap := true`

---

**ADDENDUM:** If you want to insert a `\n` after every `x` characters, I have the following snippet for you (which I quite like):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string mystr = "this is my very long text";

mystr = Regex.Replace(mystr, "(.{20})", "$1\n");

TextBox1.Text = mystr; // or: TextBox1.Content = mystr;
```

Where the `20` inside the Regex "(.{20})" your ammount of characters is, after which a `\n` will be inserted. *(meaning, that your string will have a new line after every 20 characters)*

Comment: just one moment: instead of Regex.Replace("(.{20})", "$1\n")
you should use Regex.Replace(mystr, "(.{20})", "$1\n")
Thank you.

Comment: @pavel: Right you are -- I had some kind of brain-afk. I edited my answer.

Comment: Just tested on winforms: use \r\n - \n doesn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm m-bot15"  ForeColor="#800000" BackColor="#ffe1d2" Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="48px"                                                                           ></asp:TextBox>



         e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;");
```

Answer (score -3):

This is annoying as you would expect word wrap to actually wrap the text.
I am using this workaround: Use the "Right Margin" property to set the sentence length. It will automatically wrap then.

Comment: e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;");       add this in text box control:Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine"