# Inserting line breaks in a string dynamically

Tags: c#

I have a `TextBox` where I need to show some text. The length of the text is dynamic, so it needs to be wrapped to fit into multiple lines.

The maximum length of a line is 50 characters. If the text is more than that, I need to add a line break `\n`.

For example, if the text is 165 chars:

1. Add a `\n` at 51st position
2. Add a `\n` at 102nd position
3. Add a `\n` at 153rd position

So finally the total length of text will be 168 chars.

I know how to do this using a loop. But my question is, can this be done without much code? Does the String class have a method to provide that function?

This is a Windows Forms app, but all controls including `TextBox` are created programmatically.

Comment: Environment.NewLine does not help?

Comment: what type of application is it?

Comment: You don't mind putting a line break in the middle of a word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## For Windows Forms application

You can use the WordWrap property, set it to true.

#### If you want to do it dynamically

You can do this in code, using this:

```
myTextBox.WordWrap = true;
myTextBox.Multiline = true;
```

#### If you want to do it in UI

Select the textbox and then press <kbd>F4</kbd>. Search for WordWrap, and set it to true.

Also don't forget to set your TextBox as Multiline

[image: Working sample]

@Don since you said that using WordWrap doesn't work for you, you can try using regex, like the code below:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox
    {
        Multiline = true,
        WordWrap = false,
        Width = 295,
        Height = 100,
        ReadOnly = true
    };

    var textFromDatabase = "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 111150dasdasds1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 111150dasdasds1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1111";

    var strings = Regex.Matches(textFromDatabase, ".{0,50}");
    var lines = strings.Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(m => m.Value)
                       .Where(m => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m));
    var @join = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);

    textBox.Text = @join;

    Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

Note that I'm creating a TextBox with WordWrap false and Multiline = true.

Comment: how do you suggest without knowing the type of application?

Comment: @un-lucky I tried it, he said "TextBox" and also mentioned "\n", so I thought that is a Win Form app, it could be a WPF, but I will change my question, thanks for advise!!

Comment: User top tags: Winform

Comment: @user1501127 Well noted!!

Comment: It's a Win Forms app, but there's no designer used here. All controls including TextBox's are created dynamically in code.

Comment: @don so I said how to do it dynamically

Comment: Thanks @cFrozenDeath I removed!!

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro I tried this approach earlier and it didn't work. i.e., setting Multiline & WordWrap to true. Please see this posting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534301/textbox-wrapping-text-to-multiple-lines

Comment: Seeing the question posted above me, this answer is useless for the OP.

Comment: @don This is really weird, I tried here and it works properly, are you setting Width and Height?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro I'm setting Width, but not Height

Comment: @don try setting Height to 50 and write a lot words in texbox

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro One more thing, this is a ReadOnly TextBox, so there's no user input, the text that's displayed comes from a database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99359/discussion-between-alberto-monteiro-and-don).

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Do you know of any logic in String class to insert line break after every few lines?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro I am accepting your answer for your effort and also it gave me another idea to get it working on my app.

Comment: @don Still wont work for you? I can do without using WordWrap. 
What the data that come from your database? is it a regular string? Can you paste it here?

Comment: @don I want to help, please talk to me <3

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Yes regular text string with alphabets and numbers

Comment: @don I added another solution, can you try it?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Which USING declarations i need to add for RegEx and Match?

Comment: @don System.Text.RegularExpressions

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro I did that. But get an error for Match. System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @don Add using System.Linq;

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro It actally works in wrapping text to multiple lines. So that part is fine. But the problem is the height of TextBox is not auto adjusting to show all the lines in same time. Is there a way to auto adjust TextBox based on number of lines in text?

Comment: @don Yeah, you can do it, look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893059/autoresize-textbox-control-vertically

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Using TextChanged event make it looks great! Now my last questions to you is, if the TextBox width = 100, is it possible to calculate how many characters it can hold in one line? I am sure it will depend based on Language too like Japanese or Arabic might take more space. Is there a function to calculate number of characters that can be displayed on one line of a TextBox with width set to 100?

Comment: @don The question that I sent to you to make Height autosize, the code that is used there, also is used to define how many characters can fit in width 100. You will still use the method `TextRenderer.MeasureText` but you will pass just one character in first parameter, then you will have the width of 1 char, and the calculate how many fit in 100 width