# UWP: Wrapping text at textbox doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I trying to wrap text at textBox but there are no success..

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
     <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
          <TextBox x:Name="Details" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Height="500" />
     </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

If I have long line without `\n` I have long string with horizontal scrollbar. But how I understand `TextWrapping="Wrap"` should cut this string.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534931/5543350) answer but this is not suitable for me because I can have different width of this textBox.

Also I tried to use `AcceptsReturn="True"` with no success.

I glad to hear any ideas on how to make it works.

Comment: Remove the ScrollViewer, or set MaxWidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but i'm wondering why you don'disable horizontal Scrolling.

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <TextBlock Text="TextusLongusTextusLongusTextusLongusTextusLongusTextusLongusTextusLongusTextusLongus" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Well, it works fine for met. I don't get that Point. There should always be some sort of MaxWidth, given by the parent object of the grid.

Comment: Yep, it works. Anyway, you guy's are right about the ScrollViewer inside TextBox. So it is useless anyway

Comment: Its works for me fine, it is exactly what I needed, thank you!
Frankly speaking I thought disabling horizontal scrollbar just make scroll invisible but not setting constant width.

Answer (score 1):

You don't define any sort of width restriction. Which means that your TextBox can theoratically expand infinitely in width.

Try to either set its `width` in your XAML code or its `maxwidth`.

You can also forget about the ScrollViewer. It's already a part of the TextBox and you could just add the elements that you set in your ScrollViewer as an element of the TextBox.

Justt add it like `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`